# iTextSharp not dispose after close the object

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to split a pdf and I have using this code:

```
  using iTextSharp.text;
    using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

 private static void PDF_ExtractPages(string pdfFilePath, string outputPath)
    {

        int pageNameSuffix = 0;

        // Intialize a new PdfReader instance with the contents of the source Pdf file:  

        //PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath);

         using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath))
        {

                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(pdfFilePath);
            string pdfFileName = file.Name.Substring(0, file.Name.LastIndexOf(".")) + "-";

            for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= reader.NumberOfPages; pageNumber++)
            {
                pageNameSuffix++;
                string newPdfFileName = string.Format(pdfFileName + "{0}", pageNameSuffix);

                Document document = new Document();
                PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(outputPath + "\\" + newPdfFileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
                document.Open();

                copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber));

                document.Close();
                copy.Close();
            }

        }

    }
```

and I get this error on line:

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath))


type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'
```

if I remove the using with this code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath);
```

the code work but not dispose reader object, and when I try to open a PDF I get a message like: "this document is open by another user".

There is a way to dispose PdfReader and all inside code ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

That's why it doesn't implement `IDisposable`.

You can use a `try-catch` block which is a equivalent way.

```
PdfReader reader = null;

try
{
   reader = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath);
   // Some code here
}
 catch (Exception)
{
   // Take some action.
}
finally
{
    reader.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but reader don't contain dispose method. For this reason I have posted this question.

Comment: @Marco999 Here you have [some examples of iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.Dispose](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/iTextSharp.text.pdf/PdfReader/Dispose/php-pdfreader-dispose-method-examples.html)

Comment: Thank you, I suspect that this happen becouase I have get my version from nuget package ItextSharp.LGPLV2.Core(1.7.1) that is unofficial port of ItextSharp for .net core. Can you suggest some workaround ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to use iTextSharp if you don't have any specific requirement to use that port. iTextSharp latest stable version 5.5.13.2 which is EOL, and has been replaced by iText 7 (has "hidden" pricing but it also has a free and open source version with AGPL licence) but future security fixes will be added.